# JQuery Get element using name AND id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use an element with two attributes as identifier? I got this tr element here with id and name identifiers.

```
<tr class="danger" id="event_row" name="'.$result["id"].'" data-tooltip="#popupboxm">
```

I want to use it to this event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#evnt_can', function() {
            var item = this;
            var table_row = //the two-identifier element will be use in this variable.
            var option1Value = $(this).data("value");
            var option2Value = $(this).data("status");
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url : "models/ajaxReq/req_evntcan.php",
                type : 'POST',
                data : {option1Value, option2Value},
                dataType: "text",
                success : function () {
                    if (option1Value == 0){
                        $(table_row).attr("class", "danger");
                        $(item).html("Cancel Event");
                    }
                    else if (option1Value == 1){
                        $(table_row).attr("class", "info");
                        $(item).html("Reassign Event");
                    }
                },
                error : function () {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });`
```

Comment: ID is enough for this since ID should be unique in context

Comment: Just use the ID to locate the element. It is (should be) unique

Comment: You can select by ID and name together, `'#idHere[name="nameHere"]'`, but as has already been pointed out ID should be unique so the only time it would make sense to select by both is if you don't want to select elements that have only one or other of the ID and name.

Comment: I'm using atrri("name") as an unique modifier and attri("id") as the element-identifier-triggering-event. But the real question here, CAN I use BOTH identifiers from two different attributes for an element-identifier-triggering-event???

Comment: What is an "element identifier triggering event"? You can combine as many attributes as you want into a single selector string, it's just that if you find yourself needing to do that you've probably taken a sub-optimal approach, especially if one of the identifiers is ID which should already be unique.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I'm still new to the professional programming world so I don't know some terms used by professional programming which may includes you but I use that term for lines like: `$(document).on('click', '#id', function()()` or `$(document).on('change', '#id', function()()`

Comment: I think you're just talking about a "selector" - the second argument to `.on()` (when used like that) is a selector string. In which case you can do what I said in my first comment.

Comment: thanks, it works but since it seems this is an a dynamic selector, it deletes the attri('class') of the selector. but you answered my question on how to get a two-attributed selector

Comment: @nnnnnn - Can I ask for a tip how to make the ID unique? I got a lot of rows here so I'm using its attri(name) as somewhat value in which I just found out, a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

well,I think you can use a custom attribute to merge them,then use the custom attribute as identifier

Comment: Tried this approach, made my day messier.

Comment: sorry about that.